# Using tls with jwt

Tags: java, security, ssl, spring-security, jwt

I want to use tls with my sharing of token and login process. I implemented it and it works fine. I create a new port for tls that is https://localhost:8443 but there is a security leak in my app. When i post https://localhost:8443/login and take the jwt and use it with GET https://localhost:8443/welcome everything great if i use http instead of https bad request is returned. But if i change my url with http://localhost:8080/welcome and gives the token that is taken before the app must return bad request but it returns succesful open. My server and security config is below. What am i doing wrong?

Server Config:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configurePasswordEncoder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getBCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Auth Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class AuthConroller {

    @Autowired
    private TokenManager tokenManager;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

            return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenManager.generateToken(loginRequest.getUsername()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Message Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/message")
public class MessageController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> getMessage() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("JWT demo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong? How do you think it should work? A plain http request to a https endpoint (port 8443 in your case) is indeed a bad request, not because of the token, but because of the protocol. Also your jwt is not tied to the protocol, it works over plain http if you send it that way, but you should not in production.

Comment: I not a securiy specialist and I think that if we are using tls, every method uses https instead of http. So the way that is used by /message is the custom way?@GaborLengyel